# Hybris - Hotfolder Configuration

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hotfolder

I have a csv file which needs to be uploaded in hybris. The CSV file has data which is to be loaded in different table in Hybris.

Currently , The hybris takes the CSV file , there is one mapping (i.e. impex header) for one file.

Can we have multiple impex for a single CSV file in hotfolder configuration so that the data will be loaded into different table

Thanks,
Sanjay Vithani.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to convert 1 hot folder csv into multiple output impex files is to add multiple `ConverterMapping` beans with the same prefix.

The `ImpexTransformerTask` bean will receive the input files and pass them to `ConverterMapping` beans which have a matching prefix. Each `ConverterMapping` has a corresponding `ImpexConverter`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Impex / HotFolder you can Import multiple types / tables from one file all you need to do is maintain different Headers for different type /table example below :

```
<bean id="batchProductConverter" class="de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.converter.impl.DefaultImpexConverter">
        <property name="header">
            <value>#{defaultImpexProductHeader}
                # Insert Products
                INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];varianttype(code);name[lang=$lang];description[lang=$lang];ean;manufacturerName;manufacturerAID;unit(code)[default=pieces];$approved;Europe1PriceFactory_PTG(code)[default=eu-vat-full];sequenceId[translator=de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.converter.SequenceIdTranslator];$catalogVersion
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="impexRow">
            <value>;{+0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9};{S}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="rowFilter">
            <bean class="de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.converter.impl.DefaultImpexRowFilter">
                <property name="expression" value="!row[1]"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="type" value="Product"/>
</bean>
```

by using same technique you can also populate one type / table with different files..

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple headers, you can load data into different tables. You could have as many headers as you need in one csv file.